# Code overlay in Eclipse like in Sublime text editor

Tags: eclipse, overlay, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a code overlay plugin for Eclipse like the one on the right in Sublime text editor? Here's a screenshot from Sublime text showing the code overlay on the right:

[image: Sublime text code overlay example]

Comment: PyDev implements this themselves, but the Eclipse Platform does not. I've only seen it complained about since the native scrollbar thumb is already proportionately sized according to the file length and editor height.

Comment: Do you mean the "minimap" to the right, or the part at the bottom that is highlighted in red? Seems there are a few plugins, e.g. this (first hit with Google): https://github.com/apauzies/eclipse-minimap-view

Comment: I mean the minimap to the right. I didn't know what it is called... I improvised :)

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's a duplicate to the above.